# Connect to Oracle database in dotnet mvc application

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core

Oracle released a beta version [driver ODP for dotnet core 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnetcorebeta-4077982.html)(Finally!). But I can't make it work. Does anybody did it? If yes, please send me the code or help me fixing this one \o

**Useful**: I am using Visual Code, project "dotnet new mvc" (.net 2) and I installed `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` via Nuget Add Package facility (CTRL + P, ...)
Here my code:

```
public static OracleConnection AbrirSigmaUser(AutenticacaoModel autenticacao)
        {
            try
            {

                string _connectionString;

                _connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.15)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=databaseName)));User Id=UserName;Password=***;";


                OracleConnection conexao = new OracleConnection();
                conexao.ConnectionString = _connectionString;

                //right here the program exit
                conexao.Open();             




                return conexao;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {               

                throw new Exception("Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados!" + "\nErro: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The compiler was throwing a lot of exceptions about missing dlls, so I installed them via Nuget Add Package facility:

```
//required for connection
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security.Principal;
```

After adding all dlls asked, the program goes to conexao.Open() and never comes back, throwing an unhandled exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.CreateNewPRThreadFunc(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
The program '[8860] Sensatta-Analytcs.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Is all of it really needed to make a simple connection?

If there's something missing(e.g code samples) in order to figure out my issue, just tell me!

Comment: You mention having added `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` while the package name is `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core`. Is that a typo? Can you show us your dependenceis in `.csproj`?

Comment: @Lesiak you could not be more right, thanks! But that is an error someone else might fall in too. Because when you download the zip file from [oracle link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnetcorebeta-4077982.html) the dll name is `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Lesiak stated, I used the wrong package (the right one is `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core.dll`).  But that is an error someone else might fall in too. Because when you download the zip file from [Oracle Link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnetcorebeta-4077982.html) the dll name is `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` instead of `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core.dll` that's error prone.

Comment: To be precise, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core is a NuPkg, not a dll. The problem with the link is that the download has a zip extension, not NuPkg. That is the reason why nuget doesn't notice it in local repository.

Comment: you will find the "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" if you unzip the file, inside "~/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core.2.12.0-beta2/lib/netstandard2.0". I had to move it to my project's binary folder "~/bin".

Comment: Correct, this is one way to deal with downloaded nupkg. Other is to setup a local nuget repo. But the driver is finally in official NuGet repo, so we don't have to do this.

Answer (score 30):

For me, the solution was to install the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core` NuGet package **only**.  I had `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` installed as well and I needed to uninstall them to fix the error.

Comment: Yep, that worked for me .net core 2.2 - thanks! I didn't notice before your comment that there is core version

Answer (score 2):

Install [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/) nuget package to your project.
Make sure code below is included in your .csproj file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="3.21.1" />
```

Also **uninstall "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess"** from your project.
Make sure code below is **removed** from your .csproj file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" Version="19.10.1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works putting previous version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core, the last version have any problem.