# Can't execute query against oracle in .net core

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following code:

```
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString.Value.Mix_DB))
        {
            var fish = connection.Query<dynamic>("SELECT Username, Password FROM Orderform_Users");
        }
```

When I run the code, I get the following exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type
>   'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'

I have downloaded the latest version of ODP.NET (Oracle Data Provider for .NET Core 12.2 Beta 3)

Anyone who can guide me into the right direction with this problem?

Comment: The ODP.Net provider for .net core is still in beta, are you using the correct version? (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnetcorebeta-4077982.html)

Comment: @jeroenh: Yes :)

Comment: @jeroenh what is the correct version? Im using the latest, which is Beta 3?

Comment: that should work I guess (haven't tried it). Maybe best to provide complete example showing the problem...

Comment: @jeroenh: This is the complete example..

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159199/connect-to-oracle-database-in-dotnet-mvc-application

Comment: @jeroenh: Yes, but I have installed it from nuget.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to Oracle database in dotnet mvc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159199/connect-to-oracle-database-in-dotnet-mvc-application)